# object size too big in flutter

Tags: flutter, arcore, 3d-model

I am trying to show a car in flutter **AR** the problem is that the size of the car is too big i.e. am only able to see 1/4 of the car at a time in my phone screen. So, is there anyway to reduce the size of the car so that it appears to be a small toy.

Code:-

```
final carNode = ArCoreReferenceNode(
          name: objectSelected,
          object3DFileName: model.sfb,
          position: plane.pose.translation,
          rotation: plane.pose.rotation);

      arCoreController.addArCoreNodeWithAnchor(carNode);
```

The model is obtained from poly, [model](https://poly.google.com/view/3knnxGlixiJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to prescale the model data. Looking at the obj file it is close to life size, so just multiply all the numbers after the v by something like 0.25, since 1.0 means about 1 meter to ARCore, for example in the data: v -2.072169 0.2196917 -0.5956901 the x value is over 2 meters.